# How to fix ftps connection refused issue while connecting with filezila

Tags: linux, ftp, ftps

I have configured FTPS in a linux machine but when i am trying to connect through ftps in filezila below error is coming.

Status: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server".
Error:  Could not connect to server

Answer (score 0):

FTP protocol may be blocked by your ISP firewall, try connecting via SFTP (i.e. use 22 for port num instead of 21 which is simply FTP.

For more information click [here](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration)

Comment: No firewall is running between host and client. i am trying this in internal network.

Answer (score 0):

FTPd is probably running on :21/tcp and Filezilla is trying 990, 991 or maybe 989. Try forcing Filezilla to use port 21.

Comment: i am using FTPS not ftp and i tried ftps with port 21 however it was not working